# Trouble with scope on angular-ui modal getting undefined value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have trouble with referencing the scope using angular-ui modal. I'm getting an undefined message on the value of the scope. What i want to do is to get the data that will be inputted to the ng-model="input.cost_center". However, when i adapted the examples provided by other people with regards to the same topic it doesn't seem to work.  Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance

Here is the plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/tIh5rbvseD7vxfPJHFd6?p=preview

Modal

```
$scope.openAddCenter = function () {
  var modalAddCenter = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalAddCenter.html',
    controller: ModalAddCenterCtrl,
    resolve: {
    '$modalAddCenter': function() { 
      return function() { 
       return modalAddCenter; } 
   }
  }
});

};
```

Modal Controller

```
var ModalAddCenterCtrl = function ($scope, $modalAddCenter, $http){
  $scope.input = {};            
  $scope.ok = function(){
    alert($scope.input.cost_center);
    $modalAddCenter().close();
  };

  $scope.cancel = function(){
    $modalAddCenter().dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalCenter" ng-model="input.cost_center" placeholder="Cost Center" ng-minLength="8" maxLength="8" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm unsure why the resolve is not working, it looks like what you're trying to do should be done with the $modelInstance argument that anuglar-ui will make available to modal controllers. So instead try:

```
var ModalAddCenterCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, $http){
  $modalInstance.close();
}
```

$modalInstance will always resolve to the current modal instance, rather than needing to inject it in with the resolver.

Comment: I'm still getting undefined value from the ng-model="input.cost_center" and TypeError: object is not a function. This points out to the $scope.ok function.